# Was the reason that Haskell had single-argument functions to be like lambda calculus?

Tags: haskell, arguments, currying, lambda-calculus

In [LYAHFGG we read](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions):

> Every function in Haskell officially only takes one parameter.

In this description of [Lambda Calculus we read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Motivation):

> The second simplification is that the λ-calculus only uses functions of a single input.

My question is: **Was the reason that Haskell had single-argument functions to be like lambda calculus?**

(Or is it just a combined focus on simplicity with currying?)

Comment: I think it's more historical influence. All(?) the other lazy functional languages at the time had single argument functions.

Comment: One interesting effect of this choice is how it makes it very easy to define typeclasses on function types, and it also makes the Applicative pattern quite a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell was indeed strongly intended to be like and even based on lambda calculus. A choice quote from [A History of Haskell: Being Lazy with Class](http://research.microsoft.com/~simonpj/papers/history-of-haskell/index.htm):

> The simplicity
>   and elegance of functional programming captivated the present
>   authors, and many other researchers with them. Lazy evaluation—
>   with its direct connection to the pure, call-by-name lambda calculus,
>   the remarkable possibility of representing and manipulating
>   infinite data structures, and addictively simple and beautiful implementation
>   techniques—was like a drug.